# AX Retail POS Login Customization

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-xpo

I want to make a customization into AX POS retail login module. instead of typing operator id and password, can i read externally and pass to POS with operator id and password?

Regards,
Rassal

Comment: i couldn't implement biometric login. can you please help me to implement the same?

Comment: I was able to implement a working solution after struggling for several months but the solution does not rely on the bio metric classes in AX. It is a quack solution but provides a solution for the problem. Am working to post the solution as an answer as soon as I get time. If you urgently need the solution leave me a message on my yahoo.

Comment: Hi @ShadrackB.Orina can you provide details on your quack solution for that? What projects did you modify in Retail SDK? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use logon extensibility to manage it. But it will depend on which version you are (Retail POS for AX 2012 FP, R2, R3, Modern POS).

For example, in AX 2012 R2, this is what you can find for Logon extensibility:

> Magnetic stripe reader (MSR) logon and bar code logon have been
>   enhanced, and now support an optional PIN. Support has been added for
>   additional logon devices, such as biometric devices and custom
>   peripheral devices. Partners can now also customize the logon screen.
>   See ILogOn, IBiometricDevice, and ILogOnDevice.

Comment: I am using AX 2012 FP. i would like to utilize the biometric device for login. could you please share some blogs or sample. so that i can make an attempt